# Unable to connect to any of the cluster's CLDBs

Tags: mapr, ezmeral

good morning

we currently facing an issue on ezmeral data fabric
Regarding the cluster's CLDBs it doesnt start from some reason

after looking into it we tried to update and maintain the ezmeral but it did not help as another error appeared
[image]

AnsiballZ_configure_refresh.sh failed from `'configure.yml'`; check `/opt/mapr/logs/configure.log`

in this log we see the following

2023-08-28 09:25:59.19 192.168.1.150 configure.sh(30891) Install ConfigMaprUser:406 ERROR: cldb key file `'/opt/mapr/conf/cldb.key'` or token directory `'/opt/mapr/conf/tokens'` and `'/opt/mapr/conf/maprhsm.conf'` is not available.

`/opt/mapr/conf/cldb.key` doesnt exist
`/opt/mapr/conf/tokens` exists and has 2 files mrhsm.conf mrhsm-file.conf
`/opt/mapr/conf/maprhsm.conf` exists and contain

```
# MapRHSM configuration file
directories.tokendir = /opt/mapr/conf/tokens
objectstore.type = external
objectstore.backend = file
objectstore.usealtbackend = false
objectstore.altbackend = kmip
log.level = INFO
token.kmip.retry.interval = 5
token.kmip.retry.attempts = 30
token.kmip.read.timeout = 10`
```

Are there any suggestions or where to start

1- maintain update
2- reinstall ezmeral without removing it
3- i cant even open the webserver to see any configs
4- BTW i guess this happned duo to some space issuse which i solved by removing un neccsery objects on the SSD